# How to move sidebar contents vertically in beamer class?

Tags: beamer, sidebar

My siderbar is quite full, so that the last section has no margin to the lower side of the box left. As i used a footline, the space is reduced even more. However, i didn't use short author option in sidebar, so that there is more than enough space above. I tried to include the content of beamerouterthemesidebar.sty to my file, to edit the vertical spaces definded there. But as I'm a Tex newbie, i couldnt handle the resulting errors like "missing begin document" or "beamer@(sth) not defined".
My theme is Berkeley.
I hope someone could provide a quick fix.

[image: screenshot of current sidebar]

The space between the gray square and white titletext should be used to center the content.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you showed?

Comment: Well, I am lucky.. while deleting lines in order to create a MWE, i spotted my fault at including beamerouterthemesidebar.sty. Just messed up coding here. How to delete/mark this question as solved before others put effort in answering this?

Comment: @VerzweifelterNewbie You should be able to delete your own post. However, I'll vote to close:)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved by the OP while he was building a MWE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following example, I have copied part of the `beamerouterthemesidebar.sty` to the MWE and added comments to the lines that can be modified in order to change the vertical spacing between the elements in the sidebar.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\makeatletter
  \setbeamertemplate{sidebar \beamer@sidebarside}
  {
    \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@sidebarwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by -6pt%
    {\usebeamerfont{title in sidebar}%
      \vskip1.5em% <--- Vertical space before title in the sidebar.
      \hskip3pt%
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{title in sidebar}%
      \insertshorttitle[width=\beamer@tempdim,center,respectlinebreaks]\par%
      \vskip1.25em% <--- Vertical space between author and title in sidebar.
    }%
    {%
      \hskip3pt%
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{author in sidebar}%
      \usebeamerfont{author in sidebar}%
      \insertshortauthor[width=\beamer@tempdim,center,respectlinebreaks]\par%
      \vskip1.25em% <--- Vertical space between author and first section heading.
    }%
    \insertverticalnavigation{\beamer@sidebarwidth}%
    \vfill
    \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
    \else%
      \usebeamercolor{normal text}%
      \llap{\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}\hskip0.1cm}%
      \vskip2pt%
    \fi%
  }%
\makeatother

\title{This is the title}
\author{the author}
\begin{document}
\section{Some text}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```